# Does rng-tools run at startup?

Tags: scripts, init.d

I installed `rng-tools` and noticed that is has a script in `/etc/init.d`.
Does that mean that it will run at boot? Or do I still have to run `rngd -r /etc/random` or `/etc/init.d/rng-tools start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to run on startup. It shows me when I run after a reboot:

```
sudo service rng-tools status
```

The following:

```
● rng-tools.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rng-tools; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Do 2016-05-26 20:17:21 CEST; 22min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1599 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rng-tools start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mai 26 20:17:21 NEXUS-ONE systemd[1]: Starting rng-tools.service...
Mai 26 20:17:21 NEXUS-ONE rng-tools[1599]: Starting Hardware RNG entropy gatherer daemon: rngd.
Mai 26 20:17:21 NEXUS-ONE systemd[1]: Started rng-tools.service.
```